# How to make SCSS classname unique?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am using scss in react.

I have two components that have `<img className='logo' />`

and both components have independent .scss files.

I want to customize the styles of two .logo (s) differently.

What should I do to make classnames unique when rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

> A CSS Module is a CSS file in which all class names and animation names are scoped locally by default.

React support is native, you can check-in [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)

Comment: edited for react usage

Answer (score 0):

just use different classnames for styling ex:homepage-logo , article-logo